# Font Awesome icon are not loading in wordpress 5.5.1

Tags: plugins, fonts

I have created a form using contat form7 and Elementor in wordpress 5.5.1 . Here i am getting one problem font awesome icons are not loading. for reference please find the below url

http://3.6.131.50/dentist-near-me/

We had developed same form in wordpress 5.4.2 here font awesome icons are loading.For reference please find the below url
https://jasdental.in/dentist-near-me/(Due to server issue it is taking much time to load sorry for inconvinence)
For reference please find the attached images also
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add Awesome kitcode in theme header file after put this code icons are loading.